# is there a way to limit the number of scheduled dag runs in apache airflow?

Tags: airflow, airflow-2.x, data-ingestion

We use airflow deployed by ourselves in the company I work and we have a data ingestion process that run every hour for every table in a mysql db.
The issue I'm facing is since airflow 2.x, once we are ingesting a new database and ingesting let's say from beginning of 2022, we end up with TOO MANY queued dag runs, let's say for january 2022, feb 2022, march 22, etc - this end up overloading the schedule until it stops working.
We are already using the max_active_dag_runs parameter, but that's not enough, because airflow is still creating a bunch of new dag runs in queued state, which generates the issue...

Wondering if anyone has an idea or maybe another parameter that could control airflow for him not to start queuing all of the future tasks and spinning out of control.

For now I'm kind of letting it run for a while and manually killing the exceeding queued tasks in the airflow metastore.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Queue DagRun actually means that the DagRun didn’t even start. This is very confusing (because TaskInstance  also has Queue state) thus a while ago I raised [suggestion](https://github.com/apache/airflow/issues/24045) to address this.

I think you are looking for [parallelism](https://github.com/apache/airflow/blob/3df03cc9331cb8984f39c5dbf0c9775ac362421e/airflow/config_templates/default_airflow.cfg#L59) - defines the maximum number of task instances that can run concurrently per scheduler in Airflow, regardless of the worker count. Generally this value, multiplied by the number of schedulers in your cluster, is the maximum number of task instances with the running state in the metadata database.

You can change the value from airflow.cfg or by changing the value of environment variable [AIRFLOW__CORE__PARALLELISM](https://%20https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/configurations-ref.html#parallelism)

Comment: I would rather not have to mess up in airflow general configurations - I'd like to configure something for the DAG itself - I understand what you said that the tasks are not starting, but they being on queued state consumes lots of resources from scheduler. 
I'd like to limit the number of queued tasks that this DAG itself can spam.
Before version 2.1.3 this issue would not happen...